# List all installed packages of specific repo in arch

Tags: archlinux, pacman-package-manager

Say I have the repo `foo` listed in my `pacman.conf` configuration file:

```
[foo]
Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrolist-custom
```

I want to simply list of installed packages of my system from `foo` repo.

Answer (score 2):

You can list your installed packages, list the repo packages and compare. The output will be your installed packages from repo.

```
pacman -Qq | sort > tmp_installed.txt
pacman -Slq foo | sort > tmp_foo.txt
comm -12 tmp_installed.txt tmp_foo.txt
```

If you want to do it repetitively make a script. Here an example of a script  called list_repo.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
# List installed packages from repo
if [ "$#" -lt "1" ] || [ "$#" -gt "2" ]; then
    echo "Invalid number of arguments"
    echo "Usage: $0 <repo>"
    exit
fi

pacman -Qq | sort > tmp_installed.txt
pacman -Slq $1 | sort > tmp_repo.txt

comm -12 tmp_installed.txt tmp_repo.txt
rm tmp_installed.txt
rm tmp_repo.txt
```

Run it as:

> ./list_repo.sh foo

Comment: It does not work: I have installed `abiword` from `world ` repo, but it is in `extra` and in `libre` repos too: (`pacman -Ss abiword` just gives me `[installed]` in `world`. But `abiword` **appears** in `tmp_foo.txt` for `foo=libre`.

Comment: Repositories are the list of precompiled packages. If both lists have the same package, then you will get that results. I don't know if there is way to distinguish as you wish. If you check the whole package information with `pacman -Qi abiword` there is no info from which repo was installed.